# How to implement transactions in VoltDB?

Tags: voltdb

VoltDB is in memory and ACID compliant database. How we can implement transactions in this database. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All operations against VoltDB are 100% strict-serializable ACID transactions.

There is no BEGIN, COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

If you want a multi-statement transaction, you must create a stored procedure. The run() method of the stored procedure becomes the transactional context. It implicitly starts with BEGIN and ends with COMMIT. If an exception is thrown, it will ROLLBACK.

This is covered in the tutorial: https://docs.voltdb.com/tutorial/index.php

Chapter 5 is on procedures: https://docs.voltdb.com/tutorial/Part5.php